# Swift 3 UIWebview Authentication

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, swift3

I have a login to an API which works and now want to load a web view which needs the authentication token. I'm testing my app using the Xcode Simulator for iOS 10.1.

When I load the web view I get a sign in page and a message from the API "It looks like you are not accepting cookies". Is this a case of mismatched cookies names expected or something I have missed?

```
func createWebViewRequest() {

    self.createCookie()
    let url = URL (string: "myDomain/info/wishlists")
    let requestObj = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
    requestObj.httpShouldHandleCookies = true
    let headers = HTTPCookie.requestHeaderFields(with: HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies!)
    requestObj.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    requestObj.addValue("iOS", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-My-Client")
    self.webview!.loadRequest(requestObj as URLRequest)
    self.webview!.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(self.webview!)

}

func createCookie() {

    let infoModel = UserInfoManager.getUserInfoModel()

    if infoModel != nil {
        let cookieProps = NSMutableDictionary()
        cookieProps.setValue("NIDDEV", forKey: HTTPCookiePropertyKey.name.rawValue)
        cookieProps.setValue(infoModel?.userAccessToken, forKey: HTTPCookiePropertyKey.value.rawValue)
        cookieProps.setValue(".mydomain.com", forKey: HTTPCookiePropertyKey.domain.rawValue)
        cookieProps.setValue("/", forKey: HTTPCookiePropertyKey.path.rawValue)
        cookieProps.setValue("0", forKey: HTTPCookiePropertyKey.version.rawValue)
        cookieProps.setValue(Date().addingTimeInterval(31536000), forKey: HTTPCookiePropertyKey.expires.rawValue)
        let dict:NSDictionary = cookieProps as NSDictionary

      let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: dict as! [HTTPCookiePropertyKey : Any])


       HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie!)
    }
    else {
        let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        delegate.callAuthTokenWebservice()
    }

}
```

I dumped the create cookie method above and decided to save the cookies using the response header for the immediately prior check auth call which comes from an API and authenticates in the header. This stopped the target web site from complaining about not getting cookies but it still wouldn't accept the auth key.

```
private func setCookies(response: URLResponse) {

        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            if let headerFields = httpResponse.allHeaderFields as? [String: String] {
                let _ = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: headerFields, for: response.url!)

//                print(cookies)

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should use UIWebView delegate method for store cookie.

Comment: Could you describe how in an answer please? I am new at this.

Comment: When you request for Login page on Webview and Enter user and password if valid than return cookie from server. It is right?

Comment: Yes except that I am sending the cookie to the server, or at least the server is not getting it. The app checks authorization and loads the webview only if authenticated. So now I want to set the cookie and load my UIWebView